# How do I earn the publicist badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, publicity-badges

I see "share this link to earn the publicist badge"

Where exactly do I share the link?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take the link from the `share` option directly underneath the question and then share this specially tailored link (it contains your user ID to identify you as the source) pretty much **anywhere** you like, to encourage other people to visit the link (and thus drive traffic to the site).

This could include Facebook, Twitter, any other social networking site or your blog, for example. But could extend to non-web methods, maybe sneakily write it on the whiteboards around your school / Uni / workplace, directly tell others you work / learn with, give it to with your mates down the pub, and so on...

For further information on the Publicist badge (and its family) have a look at the  [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/).

Answer (score 1):

You must share the link to any other site from where the traffic gets directed to SO

Comment: And how does SO know that the link has been shared by me?

Comment: @Kau Your userID forms part of the link. For example, when I look at the link for this question I see `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68502/147926`. The `147926` is my user ID, the `68502` is the question's ID.