# Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats, winter-bash-2016

I decided to start the traditional secret hats post, but instead of just another "here is how you get the secret hats" post, to also add in **all** the hats. There are two answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats.

---

Some notes about secret hats:

- A secret hat for correctly guessing a secret hat will no longer be awarded.
- There are no secret hats for pinging SE employees.

---

*Note*: Only edit the list of secret hats with **definitive answers**. This is not a place to post guesses. If you'd like to discuss hats further and/or work towards identifying what their triggers are, please do so in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe). Comments are not meant for that type of extended conversation.

If there are regular hats that are not listed yet, please edit and add them. If you know more specific info about one of the hats, edit that in (a source would be preferable).

Comment: Do we want to organize the secret hat discussion like I suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272367/238586)?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat there is a chatroom live right now here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe

Comment: Do you get hats for activity on Meta? Say Snapchat, do you get it for a +3 answer in a Meta question?

Comment: Am I allowed to participate if it's not winter here?

Comment: @Sklivvz who knows...

Comment: @fedorqui Yes. I have 4 hats on meta.SE. Also, one hat *requires* meta activity. *ask, answer, or vote on the meta site*.

Comment: How these Secret Hats are decided? Who make these Secret Hats, which is seen as the spoilers Answer over some Winter Bash questions?

Comment: bluefeet did, we have to find out the trigger as a community

Comment: There are **too many secret hats**. It's pointless if you just get one after another for basically doing nothing noteworthy.

Comment: @Richard Blasphemy! You can pry my abundance of secret hats from my cold, dead hands. ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I've lost interest. If you're not told what they're for (and when the names are **utterly baffling**) then they're basically meaningless. It also concerns me that some of these hats reward dumb/damaging behaviours.

Comment: @Richard Yes, if one appreciates hats mostly for their badge-like nature, it could be possible to feel as if too many secret hats that are too obscure in their awarding makes hats pointless. However, hats are for *wearing*, not just earning. That means that, for everyone else, there is plenty of point to having secret hats of any number. Winterbash doesn't just serve the gotta-catch-'em-all set. (Which is a perfectly fine motive! Just not universal.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - My issue is that despite having not *tried* for a single hat, I find myself near the top of the leaderboard. However fully half of my hats are "secret hats" that just seem to turn up.

Comment: @Richard Which is delightful, if you like wearing hats. So to ground this in the original statement: pointless for some perhaps, but not pointless-without-qualification. Quite pointful for enough people for there to be a point to having many secret hats.

Comment: @Richard this is the whole point of the winter bash. You get hats for doing *normal* things across the site. PS 21 hats in not near the top of the leader board.

Comment: @David - It's #3 on the only site I give a crap about

Comment: @Richard well good for you. but if you really don't care for the winter bash so much, there is a little button just for you called "I hate hats."

Comment: @David - I like the hats, I just wish there were far fewer secret ones.

Comment: @Richard the vast majority of the secret hats I earned were complete  surprises to me. The only secret hat I actively searched for was the Elementary one, but only because I had earned it on ELL and I couldn't figure out how, I wanted to win it on EL&U, too. I think, generally speaking, the secret hats were well thought out.

Comment: what should we do to get the secret hat? means what do they do that get them?

Answer (score 353):

## Secret Hats

Live updates during the Winter Bash can be found on [this Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AFlWPYR7xnrQRsrVTS2Q_-sLhK7Ew1hLDz5oNKlu_n0/pub) (edit link can be found in the chatroom), discussion in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe).

All criteria listed are [official](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289668/can-we-have-a-2016-winter-bash-wrap-up-with-stats).

---

#### Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it

[image: Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it]

> Edit or suggest an edit to 5 posts in a single UTC day, without commenting on the post

---

#### 180°

[image: 180°]

> Vote to close a question, be the first to edit the question while it is closed, and vote to reopen it. Hammers are confirmed to work (for both the close and open)

---

#### This Is Fine

[image: This Is Fine]

> Answer a bountied question and receive an upvote, but not the bounty. Answer must be posted *during* the bounty period but *not necessarily* during Winterbash.

---

#### Elementary

[image: Elementary]

> Edit 5 questions that were posted more than a year ago

---

#### 8,243,721

[image: 8,243,721]

> Delete 6 comments from under posts (not your own), that were edited by their owners after you commented on them

---

#### 6

[image: 6]

> 6 posts are edited by the owner after you commented on them

---

#### They Live

[image: They Live]

> In the suggested edit review queue, either "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" 5 times

---

#### Blue in the Face

[image: Blue in the Face]

> Awarded for 10 distinct comments being upvoted, all posted during Winterbash.

---

#### Mild Mannered

[image: Mild Mannered]

> Any zero-scored, accepted answer that remains zero-scored for at least 12h after accepting.

---

#### Where in the World

[image: Where in the World]
[image: Where in the World (alternate)]

> For participating on a site, when it's December 21 (the December solstice) *anywhere* in the World.
>
> (This hat comes in two forms, but you can only get one.)

---

#### The Hatter

[image: The Hatter]

> Post a question 6:00pm in any timezone. The question must have at least one upvote.

---

#### Trendsetter

[image: Trendsetter]

> Wear 5 different hats, and change your hat by using the hat rack on a site, on five different days.

---

#### Like Clockwork

[image: Like Clockwork]

> Vote between 3am and 9pm UTC (+/- 9 hours) on nine consecutive days during Winter Bash

Comment: *Blue in the Face* - those blue feet look familiar. If only I could think of who they remind me of..

Comment: Regarding *Elementary* -- "A secret hat for correctly guessing a secret hat will no longer be awarded."

Comment: @JonClements looks like a Blue-footed booby https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-footed_booby

Comment: All these hats have to do remotely with their names right?

Comment: @LPs Supposedly, it is a Sesame Street reference. See [here](https://twitter.com/sesamestreet/status/531905447142256640)

Comment: @LPs I fear it may be similar to 007 from last year but using the numbers from that post instead. Probably wrong. Anyway, there is a chat room dedicated to hat hunting - link [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe)

Comment: Trivia about the taco hat: the Community user has it.

Comment: You get "They Live" from activity in the suggested edits review queue

Comment: @Derpy http://youtu.be/nKfY6kapyBY

Comment: I just got the taco hat. Prior do getting it, I answered a question (the question had +1, not sure it's important). The question already had an answer (again, not sure if it's important). I also edited the question (without stating a summary for the edit), then got a +1 for my answer. Not sure which criteria are involved in the hat giveaway.

Comment: I just got the _Mild Mannered_ hat in Spanish Stack Overflow, but i've got no idea why. My last action was a comment in a question and after that an accepted answer with 0 rep in that same question.I consider myself Mild Mannered and try to answer that way always, but don't know what exact action made me got it :)

Comment: Where in the World theory: tomorrow is the winter solstice. badges started arriving soon after 10 UTC. 
Kiritimati is UTC+14. 
https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/kiribati/kiritimati
10 UTC is midnight Kirimati, where it just turned solstice day.
https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?iso=20161220&p2=274 Three upvotes is enough.

Comment: "Where in the World" even single upvote is enough. Even an upvote for a post written back in 2008. People mentioned that adding a comment will also qualify for a hat.

Comment: ''Blue in the face'' - Those "feet" look like the top of a cloak to me.

Comment: Hush now @DjangoReinhardt those are feet!

Comment: Where in the World - I am completely sure I received for vote. I think any action works

Comment: Looks like 180 degree don't work on your own question

Comment: Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it seems to be rewarded for 3 questions edited with no edit summary.

Comment: I got 6 (one of the Bert/Ernie ones) very shortly after a comment exchange (I left first comment on post, they responded, I responded back). Not sure if that had anything to do with it, but that's all I know.

Comment: Own question doesn't considered for 180 degree and editing only title too

Comment: @AndreiROM - nope. I have edited more than 3 questions, with no edit comment, on various sites. And don't have taco hat - so it's not that :-)

Comment: **Secret Hat Hint #1:** Blue In the Face. **10** is a beautiful number.

Comment: @bluefeet The hatter seems to be awarded if you receive the student badge.

Comment: I appear to have satisfied the criteria for an "Elementary" hat, but no hat? Do they need to be your "own" posts? Or do you mean "or later"?

Comment: I joined a site I had not been active before, got my second answer accepted within half an hour from joining the site and now have a 'mild mannered' secret hat. (Last year you could get a hat for becomming active on a new site.)

Comment: @roryalsop - I said 3 - 5. Heck, it might even be 6. I got it on 2 sites, so I think you just need to try again

Comment: Keep in mind that hats can take a few hours to be awarded.

Comment: @Brian If you've met the requirements for the hat, you should receive it within 10 minutes, as that's how often we're awarding hats.  If you haven't received it after about 10 minutes, then you didn't meet the criteria for the hat.

Comment: @bluefeet Most of mine have been showing up 30 minutes to 3 hours later. (It's easy to tell when I should have gotten 'Where in the World' or 'I Am Your Father'.) I could have been scrolling down before the notifications had a chance to appear, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @RoryAlsop It probably doesn't count your own questions.

Comment: @bluefeet I was secretly hoping that "Blue in the Face" was related to pivots in some manner since you are [the pivot queen](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpivot%5D+user%3A9003) after all. Of course to be broadly applicable pivoting would need to be related to changing your position on a topic instead of in the SQL sense.

Comment: @Erik I definitely contemplated that but then most sites wouldn't have been able to get the hat. Or it would have been far too difficult of a trigger.

Comment: I just got ***hat "6"*** on my one network (WB). All I've been doing is answering questions, and posting comments, as well as voting to close, and voting on first answers, etc. (so I voted to delete an answer, for example). I maxed out on rep 3 days straight on that site.

Comment: **8,243,721** is all about deleting comments (maybe upvoted ones). The exact number is unclear, but more than 10.

Comment: **Secret Hat Hint #2:** This time for 2 hats **6** and **8,243,721**.  [Bert & Ernie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bert_and_Ernie) have always been companions. As companions, they _could_ work together with each other.

Comment: I agree that "Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it" has to do with edits, but it does not have anything to do with not not providing an edit summary. I was awarded the hat right after I edited a bunch of posts, and I always include a summary.

Comment: @bluefeet You would say that, you're biased! ;)

Comment: [This newer user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7069510/ba-cse) has Mild Mannered on SO.  Maybe we can determine how it was earned.

Comment: The secret hat called 6 has to be to do with comments or close votes, or a combination thereof. I earned it after commenting and voting to close a couple of posts as duplicates or for not being self-contained/reproducible.

Comment: @Hack-R Nope. I got them without VTCing.

Comment: @Jamal I just received Mild Mannered this morning. The only change I had was a +10 upvote on an answer I posted to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744251/oracle-to-date-not-throwing-error/34744557#34744557) back in January. I also answered 1 question without an upvote yesterday.

Comment: I also received Mild Mannered this morning. Today, all that has happened is I received an upvote on a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269701/springboot-call-a-query-using-resttemplate/41270528#41270528) I answered yesterday and somebody said thank you to me in a different answer on the same question. I see somebody said thank you to your answer @gmiley, though it happened months ago, perhaps the upvote triggered it?

Comment: The Elementary hat can be earned by editing five questions that are at least three years old (not sure about the exact time-frame, but that worked for me on SO).

Comment: perhaps all the hats were shown on [video](http://image.prntscr.com/image/69bbcaf70da5429cb09989307d75c867.png) :)

Comment: To get a hat 6 need write a comment for the answer which will be edited after comment and will be upvote(not sure about upvote but answer was upvoted). Answer not was edited, not was upvoted, not was edited. Answer is contained one comment from the queue of poor quality audits. I add first my comment, and after 1 minute i add comment from the queue of poor quality audits. After some time i got hat, and as i can see answer was edited and has 1 upvote. All actions in period 3 hours after published answer.

Comment: 8,243,721 is definitely about deleting comments, either upvoted or not, I don't know. I just deleted around 15 of my own comments, some of which were upvoted (less than 5 upvotes) and some of which were not. Also, I deleted around five comments in the same thread. After all this, I got the hat.

Comment: Just got Like Clockwork in all four sites I participate in (SO, SU, MSE and opensource.SE beta). I'm guessing it has something to do with being active on a specific time/date? Perhaps, to borrow a clue from the name, being active at the same timeframe for X days?

Comment: Clockwork: participated on a site every day of the first week of winter bash?

Comment: @Bohemian my theory is (the same as you) but for 9 days. Dec 19 to today (Dec 27) is 9 days, not 7.

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ The 9 days theory actually makes a lot of sense. The hat and eyelashes are clearly a reference to [a clockwork orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange_(film)), where Beethoven's Ninth plays an important role.

Comment: @Bohemian additionally, if people start getting this hat on following days, we may want to relax the definition to "participate in a site for nine straight days during winterbash", not just the first nine days.

Comment: I got the "6" hat. The best I can think of is that I downvoted an answer with a comment explaining and then upvoted the answer after it was corrected (the author of the post also answered me and upvoted my comment).

Comment: **Secret Hat Hint #3:** They Live. When presented with **5** possibilities, only **2** matter.

Comment: ↑ suggested edits, `improve edit` and `reject and edit` probably (?) (I've been `accept`ing a lot  and `reject`ing a few lately, and I didn't get the hat yet)

Comment: @bluefeet Are there any more secret hats available which is not discovered yet 

Comment: @BhavinRamani Answering that would defeat the secret nature of secret hats.

Comment: I just got 6 on CR.  I last remember downvoting an answer, leaving a comment, then unupvoting and deleting the comment after the answer was improved.  I also edited the question (both posts from the same user).

Comment: Those who got **They Live**: please check the suggested edits history and look for any pattern about the *ratio* of `accept` to `reject` votes for a particular edit. For example, the hat might be triggered by very disputed edits, e.g., two-to-five (as in the hint above) votes.

Comment: I just got the **6** hat after posting six comments on questions today - but I did not cast any up/down votes on those questions. The sixth question I commented on was edited, and then I deleted my comment. But I can't remember whether I deleted it before or after I got the hat.

Comment: @Derpy Is that a reference to John Dee?

Comment: @iYoung I rolled your edit back; Elementary can be earned on other sites as well which don't have posts from 2008.

Comment: @Glorfindel Might be I posted the confirmed thing which happened for me. Also updated that on doc :)

Comment: Didn't received Trendsetter, changed hats for 3 consecutive days on SO.

Comment: I just got **8,243,721** deleting 5 upvoted comments, not the 10 suggested by @AndreiROM

Comment: @pinckerman. But I deleted 5-10 upvoted comments yesterday and *didn't* get that hat - so there must be other requirements.

Comment: @ekhumoro I deleted only comments listed in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/607992/8-243-721-eligible-comment-query), it worked for me.

Comment: @ekhumoro: [I've updated the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/610211/8-243-721-eligible-comment-query?UserId=217361) to link directly to the comment, not just the post containing it.

Comment: @Jamal. Thanks, but that doesn't get any hits for my userid. So it looks like this is a hat that is impossible for me to get (assuming the requirements are the same as in previous years). PS: has it been confirmed that only upvoted comments count? PPS: never mind - I don't even have any non-upvoted comments that fit the other criteria.

Comment: Interestingly a user on EE.SE who just had their account hacked got the Elementary hat in the process. The spammer in control of the account edited all the questions from that user, most of which were a couple of years or more old, so it may well have something to do with editing old questions. Having rolled the same questions back though I did not get the hat, so possibly something to do with questions that have had no recent activity.

Comment: Images have vanished

Comment: @iYoung Check that the 3 consecutive days are in UTC format. So the hat needs to be changed on 3 consecutive UTC days.

Comment: @code.mi thanks but I received trendsetter hat yesterday:)

Comment: @XandarTheZenon - not really. Just "second class citizens" becoming more nonsensical than usual after some of them gets deleted. Isn't that cool? Don't you enjoy reading a book with some random paragraphs removed without any indication of that?

Comment: I think just earned the elementary hat for my edit on this question : http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/51878/ I have been editing "old" questions, and been doing a lot of tag editing. I don't know what exactly triggered it though.

Comment: I disagree with "Trend setter" explanation. I just received it, of course after changing my hat, and surely it might be the third time during winter bash. But I did not change it the last three UTC days, so at least the "in a row" part seems wrong.

Comment: What is a "hammer" (in relation to 180° hat)?

Comment: @theforestecologist: Instant closure by a gold tag badge holder (based on the question) or a moderator (can also reopen instantly).

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289208/333451) satisfies the criteria: `Post a question at a UTC time that has 00, 15 or 30 as minutes number, i.e. xx:00:xx, xx:15:xx or xx:30:xx. The question must have at least one upvote.` but does not qualify, perhaps because it was closed before the script ran. Perhaps the description should be updated.

Comment: received trendsetter after removing my hat, but not changing it in weeks... definitely didn't change it 3 days in a row (i haven't been to SO the last 3 consecutive days)

Comment: **8,243,721** is obtained as follows: 1) user comments in a post 2) OP edits the post 3) user deletes the comment.

Comment: The **They Live** hat is related to suggested edits. As @bluefeet mentioned in the hint he gave earlier, "when presented with 5 choices, only 2 matter." Taking into consideration the name of the hat and the 5 possibilites offered when reviewing Suggested Edits, it seems to me that the valid options would be to **Improve the Edit** or **Approve** it. Using those two actions for a couple of reviews (not more than 10), got me the hat.

Comment: **The Hatter** hat one does not work on Meta as far as [I can tell](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/870/can-i-quote-gpl-code-here).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That works. I just deleted 5 comments on questions that the OP edited after I commented. Don't know if it works on answers, might do.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I think you have mistaken that action for the one for __6__ as I got that for exactly that sequence {comment on post, OP edits post, delete comment} of actions but it took more than the 10 minutes I'd expect.

Answer (score 190):

## Regular Hats

---

#### I Am Your Father

[image: I Am Your Father]
Ask, answer, or vote on the meta site
In case of a post, the post [must have 0 or positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288319/152859).

---

#### Running Ragged

[image: Running Ragged]
Earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.
Does not include the association bonus.
The 150 reputation per site must be earned within a 15-day period.

---

#### 011

[image: 011]
Collect 11 hats (from the same site)

---

#### Snaphat

[image: Snaphat]
Answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted (no self-answers)

---

#### First Responder

[image: First Responder]
Post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred  (room owners pinning and unpinning their own messages works)

---

#### What's Up, Doc

[image: What's Up, Doc?]
Earn reputation by contributing to Stack Overflow documentation

---

#### Fiery

[image: Fiery]
Post five answers that each get a score of at least 3

---

#### Lifesaver

[image: Lifesaver]
Answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge. The answer must get accepted and reach a positive score.

---

#### Mmmm Bacon

[image: Mmmm Bacon]
Ask, answer, or vote on December 30th

---

#### The NeverEnding Story

[image: The NeverEnding Story]
Create or update at least two items in your Stack Overflow Developer Story
(this means updating or creating two or more items in the timeline section of the story)

---

#### 925

[image: 925]
Earn a silver badge

---

#### Philantropist

[image: Philantropist]
Award a bounty, to someone else, on the last day of hats

---

#### Abominable

[image: Abominable]
Participate in successfully closing or deleting a question
(note: flagging for closure counts; flagging as spam does **not** count)

---

#### Third Time's A Charm

[image: Third Time's A Charm]
<strike>Hit the reputation cap on three different days</strike>
[Get at least 200 rep on 3 different days - regardless of the reputation cap.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34296183#34296183)

---

#### Just Here for the Hat

[image: Just Here for the Hat]
Own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats

---

#### Search You Must

[image: Search You Must]
Use *a* site's search functionality on three consecutive UTC days (same site every day, the main http://stackexchange.com one does *not* count)

---

#### Bûche de Noël

[image: Bûche de Noël]
Ask, answer, or vote on December 25th

---

#### Cutting the Cord

[image: Cutting the Cord]
Vote on seven questions or answers using the Android or iOS app

---

#### Polymath

[image: Polymath]
Post at least one well-received answer on three different sites during Winter Bash (not including Stack Overflow)

---

#### Epiphany

[image: Epiphany]
*La Befana vien di notte con le scarpe tutte rotte*
Post or vote on January 6th

---

#### Hero of Questions

[image: Hero of Questions]
Edit a closed question (that you did not participate in closing) that gets reopened after your edit

---

#### I Have A Little Dreidel

[image: I Have A Little Dreidel]
Ask, answer, or vote on any of the days of Chanukah starting December 24-Jan 1

---

#### Maverick

[image: Maverick]
Answer +5 a -3 question that goes to +3

---

#### Egoist

[image: Egoist]
Ask a question and answer it yourself, with both posts getting a score of 3

---

#### Amped Up

[image: Amped Up]
Share a link to a question on social media that gets five clicks
(All this has to be is five unique clicks on a [share link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68505/278094).)

---

#### 24

[image: 24]
Earn a gold badge

---

#### Loungin' Around

[image: Loungin' Around]
Post a question using the Android or iOS app that earns you the Nice Question badge

---

#### No Longer Grinchy

[image: No Longer Grinchy]
Participate in successfully reopening or undeleting a question
The question [needs to remain open or undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288356/152859). (When the hats award script is running, for this hat it's 10 minutes interval.)

Comment: Why do we need an answer for regular hats, when they're all listed at http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/ anyway?

Comment: @randal'thor http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34196361#34196361

Comment: I just earned Abominable on SU, where I don't have close/delete privileges. It seems that flagging would also count towards this hat (if if eventually gets closed/deleted). Should I edit this info into the post?

Comment: Shouldn't "Philantropist" be something more like "Philmyrmínkipist"?

Comment: What counts or doesn't count as social media?

Comment: @Glen_b see edit to this answer.

Comment: @Glen_b nothing (or anything, actually), it's just a misleading description. See [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288291/what-exactly-is-a-social-medium-and-how-does-the-hat-know-it/288377?noredirect=1#comment936106_288377).

Comment: i have 150 rep gained on movies, arcade, and sff  each, over the last 2 days, and have yet to receive my running ragged?

Comment: @Himarm well you have it now. Like all things in the winter bash *Just be patient*.

Comment: @David yep quite the slow one, oh well :D

Comment: I just received "Bûche de Noël" hat ... yeah, that's the *"ask, answer, or vote on December 25th"* one... yeah, it's still 24th here, I think.. unless I overslept a bit.

Comment: I just earned the "Bûche de Noël" hat!? But it's the morning of the 24th here (not 25th as per the requirements) and neither did I "ask, answer, or vote"!? (However, I have since voted.) Yet, my friend, who's in the same office and has answered a question has not received anything (but neither would he have expected to get anything, since it's not yet the 25th). @Ped7g Ah, the same! :)

Comment: What about what's up doc? for me, edit is not applicable, i guess. so what's the way?

Comment: Thumbs up for the epic Italian quote in the description of the "Epiphany" hat!

Comment: So for the Amped Up hat, [I could really just post a link right here to have dozens of suspecting people click on it??](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/36668/16866)