# What exactly is a social medium and how does the hat know it?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

The description of the *Amped Up* hat reads:

> share a link to a question on social media that gets 5 clicks

What exactly is a social medium for this purpose? Do GitHub, Stack Exchange, or e-mail count, or do I need to make an account with one of those over-hyped thingies used by people who are addicted to sharing every last tidbit of their life with the entire Internet?

Also, how does the hat know that I have been sharing via the right medium? Do I have to ensure that everybody follows the link using referrer information?

Finally, what about people who do not click links? I myself rarely use mouses as keyboards are more efficient and so do many of the people with whom I would share such a link.

Comment: That Psychic Friends Network always sounded pretty social. I'd start there.

Comment: My guess is that it follows the same rules as the badge.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat the badge doesn't care where the link was posted, as long as it's not in Stack Exchange, it just checks the user id stub of the URL (e.g. when I share [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288291/152859), the `/152859` part) and give the badge according to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This hat is similar to the [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster), and [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) badges, in that you need to share the question that gets visited by users.  The hat specifically requires 5 distinct users to open the link that you share.

To get credit for the share, make sure to use the share link under a question, copy that (makes sure you keep your User Id in it), and post it somewhere to drive users to it.  That maybe on Twitter, Facebook, etc. If 5 distinct users click the link (and they are on different IPs), then you'll get the hat.

Comment: So "social medium" can actually be any site? (e.g. some personal site, visited only by friends?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's based off your share link, so wherever you share it will work - just like the badges.

Comment: I see. So the wording "on social media" is misleading. Why not just "share a link to a question,that gets 5 clicks"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think the original idea was to limit where the clicks came from (Twitter/FB) but that was too much, so we updated it to sharing but kept the description.

Comment: So... any point starting a feature request asking to change the description, or will it be denied?

Comment: Considering hats is temporary, there is no point @ShadowWizard.