# I don't yet have my I Am Your Father hat

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, winter-bash

I posted to [Mi Yodeya Meta](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4167/5151) 4 hours ago, and did not receive the badge on that site.

Are there any hidden requirements for the badge (post a positively-scored answer?) that I need to fulfill?

Comment: [I got it](http://i.imgur.com/2a7d8tH.png)  :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer):

> most hats that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description. Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score (i.e. getting at least one upvote), not being closed/deleted, etc.

Your answer has a score of -1 right now.

Comment: So for this hat, [effortless] voting will give it to you, but [actually going and] posting an unpopular opinion won't? Just getting that straight.