# What's Up, Doc? awarded on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

In the Winter Bash 2016 promo [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U&feature=youtu.be), What's Up, Doc? seems to be awarded on Meta SE.

---

As stated in the [FAQ page](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq), this hat is unique on Stack Overflow:

> **Do any sites have custom hats?**
>
> There are two hats (The NeverEnding Story and What's Up, Doc?), that can only be earned on Stack Overflow. There are two other hats (Running Ragged and Polymath) that require participation on Stack Exchange sites other than Stack Overflow.

Meta SE has Docs too? ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

During testing of Winter Bash all hats were available to SE Employees, who wanted them, and we tested on Meta Stack Exchange.

Obviously, the screenshot was taken during our testing. Either that or Docs is very, very hidden here.

Comment: Thanks, do I get a secret hat for spotting it? ;-)

Comment: Hmm, let me think about that....Nope! :P

Comment: @Panda A worthy attempt;-)

Comment: @bluefeet Is "Blue in the face" this year's "Hairboat" hat?  Asking for a friend... ;)

Comment: @techturtle [There are no secret hats for pinging SE employees.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the post.  I'll leave this comment here in case someone else follows in my mental footsteps.