# Noticed a weird layout on users' avatar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash

I just saw something weird in the profile image of [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2315360/george):

> [image]

It also appears in the user card:

> [image]

I've searched for any legal option for it, but didn't found anything.

Looks like an SVG layer is covering the normal Avatar image, with such code:

```
data:image/svg+xml,<svg%20viewBox%3D"6.359855136413643%2031.47302727733488%20162.75770588847203%20146.71601782463097"%20xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg"%20width%3D"245"%20height%3D"221"><g%20transform%3D"rotate(19%2096%2096)%20translate(22.86035503156981%2034.46746043856381)%20scale(0.5952361747176415)"><defs><style>.cls-1%2C.cls-3%2C.cls-8%7Bfill%3A%23a4c8e9%3B%7D.cls-2%7Bfill%3A%23fff%3B%7D.cls-3%7Bopacity%3A0.34%3B%7D.cls-4%7Bfill%3A%2364a6da%3B%7D.cls-5%7Bfill%3A%23010202%3B%7D.cls-6%7Bfill%3A%2358595b%3B%7D.cls-7%7Bfill%3A%23e46586%3B%7D.cls-8%7Bopacity%3A0.3%3B%7D<%2Fstyle><%2Fdefs><title>-<%2Ftitle><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M91%2C101.2a1.94%2C1.94%2C0%2C0%2C0-.44-.44c-.13-.09-.25-.13-.29-.17s0-.11%2C0-.21a.43.43%2C0%2C0%2C0-.26-.21l.36-.24c.27.09.34.13.32.29A1.39%2C1.39%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C91%2C101.2Zm0%2C.06a1.27%2C1.27%2C0%2C0%2C1-.53-.21%2C1.32%2C1.32%2C0%2C0%2C1-.53-.89l.36-.24a.65.65%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.16.39%2C2.85%2C2.85%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.42.38.88.88%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.14.42C91.07%2C101.22%2C91.05%2C101.28%2C91%2C101.26Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M157.76%2C100.08a1.42%2C1.42%2C0%2C0%2C0-.22.5%2C1.36%2C1.36%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.26s-.08%2C0-.15%2C0a.27.27%2C0%2C0%2C0-.06.25l-.35-.26c0-.23-.05-.27.08-.26A1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C157.76%2C100.08Zm0-.07c0-.06.12.12.07.43a1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1-.57.67l-.35-.26a.44.44%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.26-.21%2C2%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.18-.45.57.57%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.31-.2C157.78%2C100%2C157.83%2C100%2C157.8%2C100Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-2"%20d%3D"M228.18%2C166.38c2.81%2C1.51%2C7.17-4.44%2C7.17-4.44s-9.83%2C1.56-17.82-2.35l-10.45-23.52%2C9.58%2C6.69S203.05%2C121%2C200%2C115l16.13%2C5.52S192.47%2C97.8%2C191%2C91.75c0%2C0%2C8.57%2C5.54%2C11.09%2C5.54%2C0%2C0-12.6-16.13-13.11-21.18%2C0%2C0%2C6.55-44.36-39.82-60.49%2C0%2C0%2C7.06-1%2C10.08-6.55a40.47%2C40.47%2C0%2C0%2C1-25.2%2C5s5.42-7.69%2C1.39-11.72c0%2C0-3.93%2C9.55-11.78%2C11.26-7.85-1.71-11.78-11.26-11.78-11.26-4%2C4%2C1.39%2C11.72%2C1.39%2C11.72a40.47%2C40.47%2C0%2C0%2C1-25.2-5c3%2C5.55%2C10.08%2C6.55%2C10.08%2C6.55C51.7%2C31.75%2C58.25%2C76.1%2C58.25%2C76.1c-.5%2C5-13.11%2C21.17-13.11%2C21.17%2C2.52%2C0%2C11.09-5.55%2C11.09-5.55-1.51%2C6-25.2%2C28.72-25.2%2C28.72l16.13-5.56c-3%2C6-16.63%2C27.69-16.63%2C27.69L40.11%2C136%2C29.56%2C159.59c-7.89%2C3.62-17.33%2C1.92-17.33%2C1.92s4.36%2C6.38%2C7.17%2C4.87c-1%2C.42-17.19%2C6.37-16.8%2C37.74H245C245.37%2C172.75%2C229.21%2C166.8%2C228.18%2C166.38Zm-54.1-79.44c-1%2C5.8-1.46%2C14.24-11.41%2C11.85s-15.7-7.56-38.38-7.06c-22.68-.5-28.8%2C4.66-38.75%2C7.06s-10.78-6-11.78-11.85%2C4.91-15.25%2C4.91-15.25a20%2C20%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C5.67c5.17-3.4%2C6.16-12.85%2C8.94-18S98.16%2C47.75%2C107%2C46.62s13.25-4.16%2C13.25-4.16c.19%2C2.27-4.44%2C8.32-4.44%2C8.32%2C5.94-2.19%2C7.87-5.14%2C8.36-6.11a.69.69%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.15-.32%2C3.27%2C3.27%2C0%2C0%2C1-.15.32c-.12.61.32%2C2.07%2C5.68%2C4%2C0%2C0-2.22-4-2-6.26%2C0%2C0%2C4.33%2C3%2C13.15%2C4.16s16.56%2C7.56%2C19.34%2C12.73S164%2C74%2C169.2%2C77.37c0%2C0-.52-3.78%2C0-5.67C169.18%2C71.69%2C175.09%2C81.15%2C174.08%2C86.94Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M245.95%2C204.13l-.2-5.52-.28-2.75c-.11-.91-.17-1.83-.31-2.74l-.5-2.72a22.39%2C22.39%2C0%2C0%2C0-.59-2.7l-.72-2.67c-.28-.88-.62-1.74-.93-2.61a21.06%2C21.06%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.07-2.55%2C22.22%2C22.22%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.25-2.47%2C25.85%2C25.85%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.44-2.37A24.81%2C24.81%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C237%2C172.8a25.37%2C25.37%2C0%2C0%2C0-3.95-3.88%2C20.94%2C20.94%2C0%2C0%2C0-2.29-1.56c-.35-.21-.74-.35-1.1-.54a3.75%2C3.75%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.8-.2%2C8.28%2C8.28%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2-1.17%2C20%2C20%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3.22-3.26l.63-.79-1%2C.11a38.34%2C38.34%2C0%2C0%2C1-8.95-.11c-.74-.09-1.47-.22-2.2-.37s-1.45-.32-2.16-.53a21.72%2C21.72%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.1-.71%2C18.23%2C18.23%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.77-.77l-8.36-19.65%2C6.19%2C4.42%2C5%2C3.55-3.17-5.27-8.35-13.86-4.08-7c-.64-1.13-1.29-2.26-1.92-3.39l12.2%2C4.31%2C7.61%2C2.69-5.8-5.66c-4.55-4.44-9-9-13.36-13.64-2.16-2.33-4.29-4.68-6.29-7.11-.26-.31-.51-.63-.76-.94.42.22.85.43%2C1.29.63s1%2C.46%2C1.61.66a7.85%2C7.85%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.93.29%2C6%2C6%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.23.18l4.28.32-2.71-3.54c-2.5-3.26-4.93-6.64-7.22-10.05-1.13-1.71-2.24-3.44-3.23-5.19-.48-.87-1-1.75-1.35-2.62a10.37%2C10.37%2C0%2C0%2C1-.51-1.26%2C4.61%2C4.61%2C0%2C0%2C1-.26-.92%2C47.79%2C47.79%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.31-4.78c0-1.7%2C0-3.39-.12-5.08s-.31-3.37-.54-5-.57-3.34-.94-5-.84-3.29-1.34-4.91l-.83-2.41-.94-2.37c-.68-1.56-1.38-3.11-2.19-4.61-.38-.76-.81-1.5-1.25-2.23s-.85-1.47-1.35-2.17c-.93-1.43-2-2.79-3-4.12s-2.18-2.62-3.4-3.8S173%2C27.14%2C171.73%2C26s-2.63-2.15-4-3.12-2.78-1.93-4.26-2.76-2.95-1.64-4.45-2.4-3-1.37-4.56-2.06c.46-.23.91-.48%2C1.35-.75a14.83%2C14.83%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.43-1%2C13.94%2C13.94%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.31-1.18%2C11.39%2C11.39%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.16-1.36%2C14.09%2C14.09%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.51l3.91-6.13L158.3%2C7.65c-.37.23-.85.51-1.3.74s-.92.47-1.39.71q-1.42.67-2.89%2C1.24a39.23%2C39.23%2C0%2C0%2C1-6%2C1.8c-1%2C.25-2.06.38-3.1.55s-2.08.25-3.13.27a30.92%2C30.92%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.14%2C0c-.35%2C0-.69%2C0-1-.07.17-.33.34-.66.5-1a16.25%2C16.25%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.11-3.27%2C11.31%2C11.31%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.26-1.78A8.42%2C8.42%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C138%2C5a5.1%2C5.1%2C0%2C0%2C0-.24-.95%2C3.53%2C3.53%2C0%2C0%2C0-.38-.92%2C4.22%2C4.22%2C0%2C0%2C0-.52-.85l-.64-.76L135%2C0l-.8%2C1.91c-.23.56-.54%2C1.19-.86%2C1.77s-.66%2C1.17-1%2C1.73a23.44%2C23.44%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.44%2C3.16%2C18.11%2C18.11%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.44%2C1.35%2C6.78%2C6.78%2C0%2C0%2C1-.77.61c-.27.18-.52.39-.8.56l-.84.48a8.26%2C8.26%2C0%2C0%2C1-.87.41%2C9.39%2C9.39%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.59.55A9.18%2C9.18%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C122%2C12a8.32%2C8.32%2C0%2C0%2C1-.89-.39l-.86-.47c-.28-.16-.54-.36-.82-.54a6.86%2C6.86%2C0%2C0%2C1-.79-.59%2C18.23%2C18.23%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.48-1.33%2C22.14%2C22.14%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.53-3.15c-.38-.56-.73-1.14-1.06-1.73s-.65-1.21-.9-1.79l-.62-1.4-.89%2C1.1-.6.73a3.91%2C3.91%2C0%2C0%2C0-.48.81%2C3.24%2C3.24%2C0%2C0%2C0-.35.87%2C4.72%2C4.72%2C0%2C0%2C0-.22.9%2C8%2C8%2C0%2C0%2C0-.07%2C1.79%2C10.87%2C10.87%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.27%2C1.71%2C15.77%2C15.77%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.13%2C3.17c.28.58.58%2C1.14.9%2C1.69-.61.07-1.22.14-1.84.15a31.45%2C31.45%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.19%2C0c-1.07%2C0-2.13-.14-3.19-.22s-2.12-.28-3.16-.51a40%2C40%2C0%2C0%2C1-6.17-1.73q-1.51-.56-3-1.22A30.78%2C30.78%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C88.4%2C8.43L85.52%2C6.7l1.81%2C2.72a13.16%2C13.16%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.92%2C1.38%2C10.43%2C10.43%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.09%2C1.25%2C12.92%2C12.92%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.24%2C1.08%2C13.8%2C13.8%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.35.92%2C18.16%2C18.16%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.92%2C1.4c.28.1.56.19.84.28-.83.31-1.65.62-2.47%2C1-1.5.7-3.05%2C1.28-4.51%2C2.07s-3%2C1.5-4.35%2C2.39-2.8%2C1.77-4.17%2C2.71-2.65%2C2-3.92%2C3.06-2.49%2C2.2-3.63%2C3.42-2.24%2C2.46-3.32%2C3.72-2%2C2.64-2.93%2C4c-.48.68-.89%2C1.4-1.32%2C2.12s-.85%2C1.43-1.23%2C2.17c-.8%2C1.46-1.49%2C3-2.15%2C4.5l-.93%2C2.32-.83%2C2.35c-.51%2C1.59-1%2C3.18-1.35%2C4.8s-.7%2C3.25-1%2C4.9-.45%2C3.3-.57%2C5-.19%2C3.33-.18%2C5A46%2C46%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C57.1%2C76a6.82%2C6.82%2C0%2C0%2C1-.34%2C1.19%2C11.3%2C11.3%2C0%2C0%2C1-.57%2C1.34c-.41.9-.92%2C1.78-1.42%2C2.67-1%2C1.77-2.17%2C3.49-3.33%2C5.2-2.34%2C3.41-4.83%2C6.75-7.39%2C10l-1.95%2C2.47%2C3-.24a5.51%2C5.51%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.09-.15%2C7.37%2C7.37%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.88-.26c.56-.19%2C1.06-.4%2C1.57-.62%2C1-.44%2C1.95-.93%2C2.89-1.43l.19-.11c-.67.86-1.36%2C1.71-2.08%2C2.54-2%2C2.4-4.21%2C4.72-6.4%2C7-4.4%2C4.58-8.94%2C9.08-13.54%2C13.46l-6.07%2C5.78%2C8-2.68%2C11.28-3.8-1.47%2C2.49-4.2%2C6.87-8.56%2C13.66-5.55%2C8.85%2C8.62-5.91%2C3.06-2.1-7%2C15.53a9.55%2C9.55%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.08.4%2C19.63%2C19.63%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.92.56c-.65.16-1.32.29-2%2C.4s-1.35.2-2%2C.25a35%2C35%2C0%2C0%2C1-4.13.12c-.69%2C0-1.38-.06-2.07-.12l-1-.11-1-.14-5.49-.78%2C3.09%2C4.48c.28.4.51.71.78%2C1.06s.53.66.81%2C1a20.86%2C20.86%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.83%2C1.89l.1.08-.56.42a29.51%2C29.51%2C0%2C0%2C0-5.94%2C6.65%2C27.73%2C27.73%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.5%2C2.52l-2.38%2C5.31c-.31.91-.65%2C1.82-.93%2C2.73l-.71%2C2.78a22.66%2C22.66%2C0%2C0%2C0-.58%2C2.8l-.47%2C2.81c-.13.94-.19%2C1.88-.28%2C2.82l-.25%2C2.82-.12%2C5.62L0%2C206.65H2.59q30.3%2C0%2C60.6-.08l30.3-.12%2C30.3-.21%2C60.6-.46%2C60.6-.72h1Zm-240.81%2C0%2C.1-5.29.23-2.62c.09-.87.14-1.75.25-2.61L6.15%2C191a21.21%2C21.21%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.51-2.55l.62-2.52c.25-.82.55-1.62.81-2.44A18.66%2C18.66%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C9%2C181.11a19.68%2C19.68%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.1-2.29%2C27.33%2C27.33%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2.72-4.2%2C22.54%2C22.54%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.42-3.52%2C18.19%2C18.19%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2-1.4%2C13.07%2C13.07%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2.09-1.08v0l.23-.08-2-4.26c.91%2C0%2C1.82-.07%2C2.73-.16s1.57-.18%2C2.35-.31%2C1.56-.29%2C2.34-.49%2C1.55-.41%2C2.31-.69%2C1.51-.6%2C2.27-.9l.77-.31.38-.85%2C10.46-23.67%2C3.2-7.25-6.49%2C4.52-1.06.74c1-1.65%2C2-3.29%2C3-4.95l4.13-7c1.36-2.35%2C2.71-4.67%2C4-7.18l2.23-4.38L46.52%2C113l-8.39%2C3c2.58-2.63%2C5.14-5.28%2C7.64-8%2C2.17-2.38%2C4.33-4.77%2C6.38-7.29%2C1-1.25%2C2-2.53%2C3-3.89a21.89%2C21.89%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.38-2.13%2C10.2%2C10.2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.64-1.17l.54-1.39%2C1.6-4.17-3.88%2C2.54c-1.7%2C1.11-3.46%2C2.2-5.23%2C3.19l-1.13.61c1.53-2.12%2C3-4.25%2C4.47-6.43%2C1.15-1.77%2C2.29-3.54%2C3.33-5.41.51-.94%2C1-1.87%2C1.47-2.88A13.5%2C13.5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C59%2C78a9.69%2C9.69%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.44-1.77l0-.09%2C0-.19A43.16%2C43.16%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C59%2C71.19c0-1.6%2C0-3.22.09-4.82s.26-3.21.46-4.81.51-3.18.84-4.76.77-3.13%2C1.23-4.67%2C1-3.06%2C1.63-4.55%2C1.29-3%2C2.05-4.37c.35-.72.76-1.42%2C1.17-2.11s.8-1.4%2C1.27-2.06c.86-1.36%2C1.83-2.65%2C2.81-3.92s2-2.5%2C3.19-3.63%2C2.3-2.26%2C3.5-3.34%2C2.48-2.06%2C3.8-3%2C2.64-1.86%2C4-2.67%2C2.8-1.61%2C4.24-2.36%2C2.94-1.37%2C4.4-2.06%2C3-1.17%2C4.53-1.76l2.49-1-2.63-.43a13.12%2C13.12%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.42-.32c-.48-.13-1-.29-1.42-.46a15.39%2C15.39%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.66-1.3A12.32%2C12.32%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C91.47%2C12c-.23-.19-.45-.39-.67-.59.93.43%2C1.87.83%2C2.83%2C1.19A41.59%2C41.59%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C100%2C14.43c1.08.26%2C2.19.39%2C3.29.56s2.21.25%2C3.33.26a33.1%2C33.1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3.34%2C0c1.12%2C0%2C2.22-.2%2C3.33-.29l1.42-.12-.83-1.24A19.5%2C19.5%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C112.44%2C11a14%2C14%2C0%2C0%2C1-1-2.82%2C9.08%2C9.08%2C0%2C0%2C1-.22-1.43%2C6.19%2C6.19%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.07-1.38%2C3%2C3%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.16-.64%2C1.79%2C1.79%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.19-.47l.26.5q.52%2C1%2C1.12%2C1.87a27.23%2C27.23%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.7%2C3.46%2C20.2%2C20.2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.62%2C1.52%2C8.29%2C8.29%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.88.69c.31.21.6.45.92.64l1%2C.57a10.27%2C10.27%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.48%2C14.65%2C14.65%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.17.73l.22.07.24-.07A14.71%2C14.71%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C126%2C14a10.35%2C10.35%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1-.46l1-.55c.33-.19.63-.42.94-.63a8.4%2C8.4%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.9-.68%2C20.4%2C20.4%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.66-1.5%2C25.79%2C25.79%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.78-3.44c.38-.56.74-1.14%2C1.07-1.73a1.22%2C1.22%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.08.38%2C5.83%2C5.83%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1.29A8.71%2C8.71%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C135.31%2C8a13.59%2C13.59%2C0%2C0%2C1-1%2C2.72c-.21.44-.45.88-.69%2C1.31s-.52.87-.77%2C1.23l-1.39%2C2%2C2.34.23c1.13.11%2C2.25.31%2C3.38.35a33.67%2C33.67%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3.4.06c1.14%2C0%2C2.26-.13%2C3.39-.22l.32%2C0%2C4.24%2C1.7c1.48.6%2C3%2C1.15%2C4.46%2C1.77s2.93%2C1.28%2C4.31%2C2.06%2C2.81%2C1.48%2C4.14%2C2.35%2C2.66%2C1.71%2C4%2C2.63%2C2.5%2C1.93%2C3.71%2C2.95%2C2.34%2C2.11%2C3.41%2C3.27%2C2.1%2C2.35%2C3.1%2C3.55%2C1.89%2C2.51%2C2.73%2C3.84c.45.64.84%2C1.33%2C1.24%2C2s.8%2C1.35%2C1.15%2C2.06c.75%2C1.38%2C1.39%2C2.82%2C2%2C4.26l.86%2C2.2.76%2C2.24c.46%2C1.51.88%2C3%2C1.24%2C4.57s.64%2C3.1.87%2C4.66.4%2C3.14.5%2C4.72.17%2C3.16.15%2C4.73a42.72%2C42.72%2C0%2C0%2C1-.27%2C4.62l0%2C.36%2C0%2C.16a10.47%2C10.47%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.5%2C2%2C14.25%2C14.25%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.68%2C1.63c.24.51.48%2C1%2C.75%2C1.5s.51%2C1%2C.79%2C1.43c1.08%2C1.88%2C2.25%2C3.65%2C3.43%2C5.41%2C1%2C1.42%2C2%2C2.8%2C3%2C4.18-1.33-.76-2.66-1.54-3.94-2.35l-4.85-3.06%2C1.91%2C5.17c.18.49.38%2C1%2C.58%2C1.47a10.42%2C10.42%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.67%2C1.2A22.12%2C22.12%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C191.75%2C97c1%2C1.36%2C2%2C2.63%2C3.07%2C3.87%2C2.09%2C2.5%2C4.28%2C4.87%2C6.49%2C7.21%2C2.66%2C2.82%2C5.38%2C5.56%2C8.12%2C8.28l-8.88-2.93-3.8-1.26%2C1.85%2C3.49c1.31%2C2.48%2C2.7%2C4.78%2C4.1%2C7.11l4.25%2C6.92%2C5.38%2C8.53-4.57-3.12-3.46-2.36%2C1.75%2C3.77%2C10.82%2C23.35.13.28.22.09c.73.29%2C1.43.65%2C2.18.88a23.1%2C23.1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.24.68c.75.19%2C1.51.35%2C2.28.48s1.53.24%2C2.3.31a37.21%2C37.21%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C8.15-.1%2C18.51%2C18.51%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.3%2C2.44%2C7.7%2C7.7%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.8%2C1.16%2C3.43%2C3.43%2C0%2C0%2C1-1%2C.26l-.47%2C0-.53-.18-.17.44a15.27%2C15.27%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2.37%2C1.27%2C20.31%2C20.31%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2.16%2C1.59%2C24.59%2C24.59%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.68%2C3.9%2C25.73%2C25.73%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.53%2C2.21%2C24.89%2C24.89%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.33%2C2.33%2C21.3%2C21.3%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.13%2C2.43%2C20.12%2C20.12%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C2.51c.27.85.57%2C1.7.82%2C2.56l.61%2C2.62a21.48%2C21.48%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.5%2C2.64l.4%2C2.66c.11.89.15%2C1.79.22%2C2.69l.19%2C2.69%2C0%2C4.45Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M174.32%2C87c-.46%2C2.75-.73%2C5.6-1.9%2C8.26a7.44%2C7.44%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.73%2C3.39%2C7.64%2C7.64%2C0%2C0%2C1-4.28%2C1A34.31%2C34.31%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C157%2C98c-2.71-.8-5.38-1.64-8.06-2.3a62.94%2C62.94%2C0%2C0%2C0-8.11-1.42c-2.73-.26-5.47-.43-8.23-.49s-5.45%2C0-8.34.06l-4.21%2C0c-1.37%2C0-2.73%2C0-4.1.11-2.74.14-5.47.36-8.18.69a81.07%2C81.07%2C0%2C0%2C0-8%2C1.52c-2.66.65-5.29%2C1.51-8%2C2.34-1.35.42-2.74.81-4.13%2C1.15-.74.15-1.34.33-2.18.47a14.92%2C14.92%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.19.24%2C8.75%2C8.75%2C0%2C0%2C1-4.69-.93A8%2C8%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C75.27%2C96c-1.44-2.74-1.72-5.65-2.19-8.4L73%2C87.11l-.06-.58a6.41%2C6.41%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0-1.1%2C14.28%2C14.28%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.22-2.25A27.4%2C27.4%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C74.31%2C79%2C46.59%2C46.59%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C78%2C71.29l.94-1.59.46%2C1.8a11.81%2C11.81%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.29%2C3.05c0%2C1-.07%2C1.94-.18%2C2.93l-1.33-.83A12.12%2C12.12%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C82%2C71.19c.89-2.17%2C1.53-4.48%2C2.24-6.82.35-1.17.72-2.36%2C1.15-3.55a19%2C19%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.68-3.51%2C23.67%2C23.67%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2.37-3.16%2C29.87%2C29.87%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2.75-2.71%2C29%2C29%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.07-2.34%2C33%2C33%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.36-1.93%2C28%2C28%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.6-1.5%2C23.77%2C23.77%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.82-1c1.24-.23%2C2.43-.41%2C3.51-.65s2.25-.51%2C3.34-.86A32.14%2C32.14%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C116.12%2C42a19.5%2C19.5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.82-1.44l3.47-2.29.08%2C4a5.57%2C5.57%2C0%2C0%2C1-.06%2C1.17%2C6.71%2C6.71%2C0%2C0%2C1-.21.87%2C12.72%2C12.72%2C0%2C0%2C1-.53%2C1.4c-.38.84-.8%2C1.6-1.23%2C2.34s-.88%2C1.44-1.34%2C2.13-.92%2C1.36-1.44%2C2.06L115%2C48.53a19.92%2C19.92%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C4.16-2.15A11.32%2C11.32%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C120.79%2C45a6.29%2C6.29%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.11-1.47l-.23.66a3.34%2C3.34%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.22-.71%2C3.24%2C3.24%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.19-.36l.13-.19.08-.11.16-.19%2C11.09-13-6.87%2C15.59-.27.6.23-.66a1.36%2C1.36%2C0%2C0%2C0-.12-1c0-.06%2C0%2C0%2C.14.13a6.18%2C6.18%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.06.7%2C22.26%2C22.26%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3%2C1.31L127.59%2C50l-.44-.84-.39-.82c-.25-.55-.49-1.12-.71-1.71a14.92%2C14.92%2C0%2C0%2C1-.58-1.9%2C9.6%2C9.6%2C0%2C0%2C1-.19-1.1%2C7.41%2C7.41%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0-1.33L125.5%2C38l3.76%2C2.39c.26.16.8.49%2C1.26.71s1%2C.47%2C1.48.69a30.84%2C30.84%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3.17%2C1.13c1.08.33%2C2.19.6%2C3.31.84.56.1%2C1.12.23%2C1.69.31l1.82.3.9.16%2C1%2C.24a16.47%2C16.47%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C2%2C.57%2C28.64%2C28.64%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.64%2C1.53%2C32.93%2C32.93%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.38%2C2%2C29.64%2C29.64%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.08%2C2.39A30.54%2C30.54%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C158.71%2C54%2C22%2C22%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C161%2C57.14a16.35%2C16.35%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.94%2C1.8c.24.53.48%2C1.17.72%2C1.8.42%2C1.22.77%2C2.41%2C1.09%2C3.59.65%2C2.36%2C1.24%2C4.67%2C2.08%2C6.85a12.2%2C12.2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3.74%2C5.56l-1.15.73c-.09-1-.13-1.94-.12-2.92a12.18%2C12.18%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.33-3l.33-1.25.63%2C1.1a47.39%2C47.39%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C3.44%2C7.47%2C24.1%2C24.1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.12%2C4%2C8.1%2C8.1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.16%2C1%2C8.59%2C8.59%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C.09%2C1A10.65%2C10.65%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C174.32%2C87Zm-.47-.08a10.19%2C10.19%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.06-2%2C8.13%2C8.13%2C0%2C0%2C0-.11-1%2C7.7%2C7.7%2C0%2C0%2C0-.17-1%2C23.5%2C23.5%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.17-3.84%2C34.38%2C34.38%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.7-3.66c-.63-1.19-1.3-2.37-2-3.48l1-.14a10.12%2C10.12%2C0%2C0%2C0-.09%2C2.68c.06.92.18%2C1.86.34%2C2.75l.28%2C1.63-1.43-.9a14.45%2C14.45%2C0%2C0%2C1-4.89-5.92c-1.13-2.25-2-4.59-2.84-6.84-.43-1.13-.88-2.23-1.35-3.27-.23-.48-.46-1-.78-1.51a13%2C13%2C0%2C0%2C0-.88-1.34%2C23.85%2C23.85%2C0%2C0%2C0-2.19-2.5%2C26.51%2C26.51%2C0%2C0%2C0-2.56-2.2%2C33.38%2C33.38%2C0%2C0%2C0-2.8-1.89%2C28.43%2C28.43%2C0%2C0%2C0-3-1.56%2C24%2C24%2C0%2C0%2C0-3.12-1.14c-.53-.16-1.05-.31-1.55-.4-.26-.06-.48-.12-.76-.17l-.9-.14-1.77-.25c-.63-.08-1.26-.21-1.89-.31-1.26-.24-2.51-.51-3.76-.87a35.82%2C35.82%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.71-1.24c-.61-.25-1.22-.51-1.83-.81a15.19%2C15.19%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.91-1.07l4-1.88a3%2C3%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.33%2C4.56%2C4.56%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.1.54%2C9.92%2C9.92%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.39%2C1.28c.16.45.35.9.56%2C1.36l.32.68.33.63%2C3.06%2C6-6.17-2.33a27.06%2C27.06%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.69-1.65%2C11%2C11%2C0%2C0%2C1-2-1.34%2C5.74%2C5.74%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.07-1.23%2C3.72%2C3.72%2C0%2C0%2C1-.56-2.7l.23-.66a.07.07%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0l4.22%2C2.6.13-.15.06-.07.08-.12a1.77%2C1.77%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.1-.2%2C1.7%2C1.7%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.12-.37l-.23.66a11.11%2C11.11%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.09%2C2.71%2C16.26%2C16.26%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.43%2C1.93A24.73%2C24.73%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C116.61%2C53l-7.79%2C2.82%2C5.06-6.52c.44-.57.91-1.2%2C1.34-1.82s.85-1.25%2C1.25-1.88.75-1.26%2C1-1.86a8.54%2C8.54%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.34-.82%2C2.31%2C2.31%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.08-.29c0-.11%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0l3.55%2C1.69a22.75%2C22.75%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.7%2C1.81%2C36.52%2C36.52%2C0%2C0%2C1-3.68%2C1.22c-1.24.35-2.48.62-3.74.85s-2.53.36-3.69.52a19.76%2C19.76%2C0%2C0%2C0-3.26.69%2C24.12%2C24.12%2C0%2C0%2C0-3.17%2C1.16%2C29.17%2C29.17%2C0%2C0%2C0-5.86%2C3.51%2C26.56%2C26.56%2C0%2C0%2C0-2.6%2C2.24%2C21.17%2C21.17%2C0%2C0%2C0-2.19%2C2.53%2C16%2C16%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.67%2C3c-.47%2C1.07-.9%2C2.17-1.3%2C3.31C85.82%2C67.42%2C85%2C69.77%2C83.94%2C72a21.45%2C21.45%2C0%2C0%2C1-2%2C3.3%2C12.3%2C12.3%2C0%2C0%2C1-2.86%2C2.74l-1.6%2C1.07.27-1.9c.13-.9.22-1.83.26-2.74a10.53%2C10.53%2C0%2C0%2C0-.14-2.61l1.4.21a44.08%2C44.08%2C0%2C0%2C0-3.66%2C7.4%2C22.52%2C22.52%2C0%2C0%2C0-1.08%2C3.93%2C13.26%2C13.26%2C0%2C0%2C0-.17%2C1.94%2C5.17%2C5.17%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.06%2C1l.05.47.09.52c.5%2C2.75%2C1%2C5.53%2C2.29%2C7.74A5.77%2C5.77%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C83%2C97.94a12.68%2C12.68%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2-.36c.54-.12%2C1.28-.37%2C1.9-.55%2C1.3-.42%2C2.59-.89%2C3.89-1.39%2C2.6-1%2C5.24-2.06%2C8-2.94a63.88%2C63.88%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C17-3c1.43-.09%2C2.88-.09%2C4.32-.14l4.22.07%2C4.22%2C0c1.43.06%2C2.86.12%2C4.28.24a65.45%2C65.45%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C16.85%2C3.39c2.71.92%2C5.31%2C2%2C7.9%2C3.09%2C1.3.52%2C2.59%2C1%2C3.91%2C1.41.68.2%2C1.33.43%2C2%2C.56l1%2C.23%2C1%2C.11a6.75%2C6.75%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C3.83-.72%2C6.55%2C6.55%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C2.6-3C173%2C92.49%2C173.35%2C89.66%2C173.85%2C86.9Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M124.14%2C44.67a3.27%2C3.27%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C.15-.32A.69.69%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C124.14%2C44.67Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-3"%20d%3D"m169.2%2077.37c-5.17-3.4-6.14-12.85-8.91-18s-10.52-11.59-19.34-12.73-13.15-4.16-13.15-4.16c-0.19%202.27%202%206.26%202%206.26-5.36-2-5.8-3.43-5.68-4-0.49%201-2.42%203.92-8.36%206.11%200%200%204.63-6%204.44-8.32%200%200-4.43%203-13.25%204.16s-16.58%207.49-19.36%2012.65-3.77%2014.62-8.94%2018a20%2020%200%200%200%200%20-5.67s-5.92%209.45-4.91%2015.25%201.83%2014.24%2011.78%2011.85%2016.07-7.56%2038.75-7.06c22.68-0.5%2028.43%204.66%2038.38%207.06s10.4-6%2011.41-11.85-4.91-15.25-4.91-15.25c-0.48%201.92%200.05%205.7%200.05%205.7z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-4"%20d%3D"m123.9%2081.07c-6.76%200-12.65%205.39-15.89%209.89a98.59%2098.59%200%200%201%2016.27%20-0.82%2099.38%2099.38%200%200%201%2015.43%200.71c-3.25-4.47-9.1-9.78-15.81-9.78z"><%2Fpath><ellipse%20class%3D"cls-5"%20transform%3D"translate(-25.12%20118.8)%20rotate(-48.78)"%20cx%3D"118.4"%20cy%3D"87.1"%20rx%3D"2.14"%20ry%3D"1.62"><%2Fellipse><ellipse%20class%3D"cls-5"%20transform%3D"translate(-25.47%20106.5)%20rotate(-41.22)"%20cx%3D"128.8"%20cy%3D"87.1"%20rx%3D"1.62"%20ry%3D"2.14"><%2Fellipse><path%20class%3D"cls-6"%20d%3D"m146.8%20119.1a10.2%2010.2%200%200%200%20-8.52%20-15.92h-30.4a10.2%2010.2%200%200%200%20-8.52%2015.92%2028.57%2028.57%200%200%200%207.32%207.38%2020.4%2020.4%200%200%201%2033.21%20-0.3%2028.61%2028.61%200%200%200%206.91%20-7.08z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-7"%20d%3D"m123.4%20117.7a20.45%2020.45%200%200%200%20-16.72%208.68%2028.59%2028.59%200%200%200%2033.21%20-0.31%2020.44%2020.44%200%200%200%20-16.49%20-8.37z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M52.78%2C203.87c.51-2.47%2C1.11-4.69%2C1.76-7s1.38-4.51%2C2.16-6.73%2C1.64-4.4%2C2.56-6.54%2C2-4.23%2C3-6.27c-.46%2C2.27-.86%2C4.52-1.12%2C6.79s-.47%2C4.53-.58%2C6.8-.17%2C4.53-.16%2C6.78.09%2C4.55.27%2C6.64Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M190.29%2C204.36c.18-2.09.25-4.41.27-6.64s0-4.51-.16-6.78-.31-4.53-.58-6.8-.66-4.52-1.12-6.79c1.08%2C2%2C2.12%2C4.12%2C3%2C6.27s1.79%2C4.32%2C2.56%2C6.54%2C1.51%2C4.46%2C2.16%2C6.73%2C1.25%2C4.52%2C1.76%2C7Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-8"%20d%3D"M177.26%2C204.59c1-5.8-4.91-15.25-4.91-15.25a4%2C4%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.57%2C2.49c-5.17-3.4-4.55-9.67-7.32-14.84s-10.52-11.45-19.34-12.58-16.8-2.09-16.8-2.09l3.88%2C4.44s-12.22-3.48-21-2.35-16.61%2C7.49-19.38%2C12.65-2.18%2C11.4-7.35%2C14.8a4.09%2C4.09%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.58-2.51s-5.92%2C9.44-4.91%2C15.24"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"m69.19%20134.9q-2.44%205.51-5.33%2010.73c-1.91%203.49-3.94%206.91-6.1%2010.24%201.78-3.54%203.4-7.16%204.91-10.81s2.87-7.35%204-11.09z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"m158.1%20128c1.18%203.74%202.54%207.44%204%2011.09s3.13%207.27%204.91%2010.81c-2.16-3.33-4.18-6.75-6.1-10.24s-3.7-7.06-5.33-10.73z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"m183.8%20144.9c0.75%202.59%201.62%205.16%202.59%207.7s2%205.07%203.2%207.54c-1.55-2.26-3-4.59-4.39-7s-2.68-4.83-3.87-7.35z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"m133.2%20137.8a68.14%2068.14%200%200%200%203.71%2012%2069.41%2069.41%200%200%201%20-6.22%20-11.22z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"m173.3%20108.4a68.14%2068.14%200%200%200%207.62%2010%2069.41%2069.41%200%200%201%20-9.72%20-8.38z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M87.45%2C161.42A53.63%2C53.63%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C83%2C170.5a52.36%2C52.36%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1.88-9.66Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M168.89%2C47.58a53.64%2C53.64%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1.8%2C10%2C52.37%2C52.37%2C0%2C0%2C0-4.21-8.89Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M141.39%2C26.91a53.62%2C53.62%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C6.78%2C7.51%2C52.35%2C52.35%2C0%2C0%2C0-8.27-5.33Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M97%2C33.39a52.35%2C52.35%2C0%2C0%2C0-9.27%2C3.29A53.63%2C53.63%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C96%2C30.93Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M82.36%2C55.45a52.35%2C52.35%2C0%2C0%2C0-6.69%2C7.21%2C53.63%2C53.63%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C4.71-9Z"><%2Fpath><path%20class%3D"cls-1"%20d%3D"M84.38%2C115.65%2C82.68%2C125.7c-.3%2C1.68-.61%2C3.36-1%2C5a17.14%2C17.14%2C0%2C0%2C1-1.75%2C4.81A16.84%2C16.84%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C81%2C130.61c.18-1.68.27-3.37.35-5.06l.4-10.2Z"><%2Fpath><%2Fg><%2Fsvg>
```

What's going on?

Comment: -1 for not knowing about winter bash.

Comment: On your right side of screen where meta posts are shown there is a blog section in which there is a link for winterbash read it!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's not a bug, [it's a Hat](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016).

It's time for [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/). If you want to know the story of Hats, then I'd recommend [watching the hat-u-mentary](https://youtu.be/CDi_nj1-G6U).

But seriously, that's one of the many hats users can earn from today through 08 January 2017 during our annual event called Winter Bash.

Comment: Definitely not a bug; it's clearly some sort of mammal.

Comment: Congrats on being the fastest gun :P

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug; it's [Winterbash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

This user has earned the [Abominable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/295232) hat and wears it now.

[image: Abominable hat]

Answer (score 0):

That's a hat for [winter bash](//http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).