# How can I check why (and what I did) for win a secret hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I have recently win the **Where in the World?** hat in [Stack Overflow En Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), but, I don't know what I did for win this hat.

When I check the hats that I win so far, I can't check why I win it:

[image: This is a secret hat.]

I consider that when any user wins a secret hat, the *secret* would be available for the user.

---

*Without spoil the other secret hats*, there is a way to check how *and why* I win this secret hat?

Comment: No, but you can check the [list of hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats).

Comment: I can tell you this much, my "Where in the world" hat looks different from yours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It wouldn't be much of a secret if it immediately told you why you got it, would it?  Take some time to try to figure it out; it's more fun that way.

Or, if you just want to look it up, check [this community-curated post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/162102).  Discoveries are hidden in spoiler blocks, so you won't see descriptions of other secret hats if you're careful about where you move your mouse.  Note that these discoveries are what people think they've figured out; they haven't been confirmed by SE.  The team reveals the secrets after the end of WinterBash.

Comment: Discoveries are hidden, and also not yet confirmed by us.  Confirmation of hats triggers will take place after Winter Bash ends this year.

Comment: @bluefeet good point; I should have been more clear that these are speculative, not confirmed.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't.

It wouldn't be a particularly good secrecy scheme if you could trace the circumstances that lead to your being awarded the hat.