# Why did I not get Snaphat for the question linked?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

The [documentation of the hat *Snaphat*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272) reads:

> answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted

Over at Chemistry, I [answered](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64801) this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/64797). The question’s timestamp reads `2016-12-19 23:41:47Z`, while my answer’s reads `2016-12-20 00:04:41Z`. Assuming I did my maths correctly, that means the answer was posted 22:54 min after the question, i.e. within the 30 minute limit. It also has a score of +3 at the time of writing this, and was accepted.

Going by my understanding of the quotation above, I should have gotten Snaphat, which I do not have as of now.

For reference, [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/64801/timeline) is the answer timeline and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/7475/jan?tab=reputation) is a link to the rep tab of my profile. The latter shows when the three upvotes and the accepting occured.

Comment: If I had to guess, the date change was to blame.

Comment: We're looking into it.