# Why did I get hats apparently without doing anything?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I earned a "Just Here for the Hats" hat on a stackexchange site (https://unix.stackexchange.com/) without doing anything. I think I didn't post a question, answer, comment neither did my questions, answer or comments get voted or commented recently.

Maybe I just visited the site (I'm not even sure about this). Is it enough to earn such a hat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got *Where in the World* on Unix & Linux, which was awarded for any participation when it was the day of solstice anywhere on the world (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/255554)). For example, it would have sufficed to cast any vote during that time.

This hat made you meet the requirements for *Just Here for the Hats:*

> own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats

Since this hat is awarded once the twentieth hat was earned on the site, it did not have to be triggered by any activity of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I'm wondering what kind of "participation" got me the "Where in the World" hat. I don't remember having done anything particular on Unix & Linux on december the 21st. Ah, I see that I upvoted a post an hour ago, and it was still december the 21st in Alaska at that time.

Answer (score 4):

You get that hat if you have any other hat on that stack exchange site, and the total number of unique hats gained by all users of that site reaches 20.

Therefore, once you have a single hat on a site, you don't have to do anything else to get "Just Here for the Hat" (assuming other users do the hard work for you).

This is explained in the [hat's description](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) :

> own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats