# Did all hats disappear now?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash

I can't find any mention of my hats, now the Winter Bash has ended. Is there a way to look at them, like an old box of souvenirs?

Comment: You can find a GitHub repo I created with all the hats over here: [How can I save my hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288812/how-can-i-save-my-hats/)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Wow seriously?! I'm sorry to have disturbed you, but what did I say to upset you people that much?

Comment: @Bebs I didn't downvote you, but MSE is not a forgiving place, and any "obvious" questions (one which the community expects the OP to have easily been able to answer for himself through a quick search or  he official documentation) tend to get downvoted swiftly and mercilessly.

Comment: @DanBron... I didn't find the answer with some keywords I have tried, that's why I thought I could ask the question.

Comment: I'm sorry to have offended you guys. I asked for this question to be removed...

Comment: Don't look at me, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Ok. Alex... It seems that I received a blast of hate for my first question and people didn't even take the time to explain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the second question [in here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq).

> ## What happens after January 8th?
>
> After January 8th, the sites go back
> to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun
> end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

This means that the hats are gone. They were here just for fun.
I'm waiting for a blog post explaining all the secret hats and some general statistics, [like the ones from 2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/) but your own  stats are gone forever.

You can still check the hats you got [in here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) but I'm not sure for how long will this be available.

**[EDIT]**

[Here is the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/) post explaining all the secret hats and some statistics.