# Why do we have to delete 10 comments in order to earn hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

> To earn **This is Fine** hat it requires us to delete 10 comments from
>   2017.

My curiosity is: Why does this site encourage people to delete their comments in order to earn hats? Is it to make this site clean?

Comment: According to what @JourneymanGeek said, probably no.

Comment: there was a secret hat in prior Winterbash: ["8,243,721"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/165773) - _Delete 6 comments from under posts (not your own), that were edited by their owners after you commented on them_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Darn. I can't submit that as an answer... Ugh....

OK... Comments... are transient. They're not intended to stick around forever, particularly comments like

> +1 OMG this answer is parfection embodied in text. Love it!
>   Thanks so much, this is just what I needed.

Also, comments that have been addressed by an edit don't need to stick around for posterity.

In fact, in the magical perfect world that isn't what Stack Exchange is right now, comments would only be used for two things:

> 1. To ask for clarification.
> 2. To ask for more information.

In fact, it's explained right here:

[image: Add a comment box. Text reads "Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering in comments.]

Actually, the comments note is slightly different on answers, but it's similar.

[image: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".]

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

And, if those clarifications, additional information, and suggestions are added, the comment would be removed... in a magical alternate Stack Exchange universe...

So, comments on Stack Exchange actually serve a specific purpose and they're pretty much always overused.

This hat trigger is a reminder to go back, look at your hundreds... um... thousands? of comments... and see if they're all still *necessary*.

Oh, and flag a few as no longer needed if you removing yours makes the comments section confusing and they are actually no longer needed.

---

If you'd like more info on comments, I encourage you to read the [comment everywhere privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for examples of good and bad types of comments.

Answer (score 4):

Gotta admit. Its *pretty* cunning. You're going to delete your comments, maybe flag a few that make no sense without it. Since comments are *meant* to be cleaned up (even if people complain)...

[Its almost like a reverse vending machine](http://beachpackagingdesign.com/boxvox/lucky-can-reverse-vending-machine), encouraging folks to clean up after themselves.

[image]

Comment: Interesting image

Comment: The only reason I leave comments is to earn a hat when I delete those comments ....

Comment: @rene flagged that for you. :-)