# Isn't there a hat for a bounty receiver?

Tags: discussion, bounties, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I just got awarded a bounty in this site, but I don't see any hat appearing.

Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a Bounty Hunter hat back in Winter Bash 2013, awarded for winning a bounty:

[image]

Unlike other hats, this one wasn't used again, I guess because it caused many people to award bounties just for sake of the hat, and not based on the actual contents.

Comment: Off-topic: I like the way you wear your hat, different from the norm, nice!

Comment: @gsamaras hehe, you probably didn't notice, but I let my daughter wear the hat. (See the bigger avatar in profile. ;)) (Also, feel free to jump into chat for as much off topic stuff as you want. :))

Answer (score 6):

Unlikely. None of the [regular hats](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) have this trigger; it could be one of the secret hats, but most of those get awarded within an hour.

In the past, there have been hats for posting a bounty and also *missing* a bounty (e.g. [This Is Fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232) from 2016) as a sort of consolation prize, but AFAIK never for being awarded a bounty (edit: see Shadow Wizard's answer, there was one back in 2013). The bonus reputation is enough of a reward already, I guess :)

Comment: Also missing is the hat called "24" (earn a gold badge) mentioned at the link you offered, tough to complain about secret hats that may no longer be offered; really rubs it in when there's a publicized hat for silver badges. I'm quite happy with my glasses, I probably wouldn't want the 24 hat in any event, so no value in writing up a posts on Meta to ask about what they can not say and I do not want/care.