# Add positive replacement for Tumbleweed badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, tumbleweed-badge, lifejacket-lifeboat-badges

I'm happy with [retiring Tumbleweed and Reversal badges](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/).

Especially I like how Reversal badge was treated. It wasn't just retired: it was replaced by Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges, utilizing the positive effect of Winter Bash, encouraging people to search for hidden gems in questions, improve them and this not only for 2 weeks.

Unfortunately, much more frequent Tumbleweed badge wasn't treated so good. It was just retired without positive replacement and encouraging any effort from users to answer these unheeded questions. I'm sure getting a good answer would encourage users to stay here much more than receiving nothing.

Also, we had this kind of hat at [Winter Bash 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/346987) to encourage answering questions with Tumbleweed badge:

#### Lifesaver

[image: Lifesaver hat from Winter Bash 2016]

> Answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge. The answer must get accepted and reach a positive score.

---

So can this "Lifesaver" badge be added? We can name it "Lifebelt". I'm sure this bronze sibling would be useful for Lifejacket and Lifeboat family.

---

I'm trying to suggest a way to encourage people to focus on answering abandoned questions. Existing [Revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/revival) and [Necromancer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badges encourage answering just old questions and it's more profitable (from point of getting these badges) to answer popular questions rather than abandoned ones.

Comment: I like this whole "life" theme ... LifeOverflow ...

Answer (score 3):

There's already a badge for this kind of action (albeit not a 1:1 fit): [Necromancer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

The criteria are:

> Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

So what you are requesting would really be an adjustment to this badge, not the creation of an entirely new one. However, I don't think an adjustment is necessary, personally; I think Necromancer fills the void just fine already.

Comment: And probably [Revival](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/revival) too…

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Yes, that would definitely fill another part of the void (bit easier to get than Necromancer)

Comment: But let's be honest: these badges encourage providing answers for old questions and it's more profitable for getting these badges to answer popular questions instead of abandoned.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I'm not sure I agree. Necromancer doesn't discriminate between "popular" or "unpopular" questions, and Revival even requires that your answer be the *first* answer. Besides, posting an answer to such a question in the hopes of earning Revival or Necromancer serves to bump the question to the front page, making it active again.

Comment: The OP proposes a badge for answering a question that has received **no interaction** in its first week. This is very different from answering an old question. I have received necromancer badges for answering old, very popular questions that already had many answers, simply adding a new way to solve the problem. That is not what OP's proposal is about. It's about answering questions that otherwise would end up abandoned, unanswered and lonely.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As mentioned in the comments, Revival fills the "no other activity" gap otherwise left by what Necromancer fills.

Comment: Also, what constitutes "old" is relative for users; some people think a question is old when it is 24 hours old, while others put the threshold at a year. In short, a question that is over a week old is, in the eyes of many, already old. (QED, it's not that different and, in fact, could be considered the same by some)